# Why mapStateToDispatch is not sending the right value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to send an action from my component to update the state. usually, I put all my action creators in the connect function like - connect(mapStateToProps,{actions})(component).

But after watching a tech tuts I thought to make a mapDispatchToProps to my connect HOC.

Now the problem I am facing is that, in my usual way the state is updating with the correct payload. but whenever I am trying to insert the mapDispatchToProps in my connect HOC, the action is firing but the payload is not being sent.

I am attaching the code snippet for easier understanding

```js
//actions ------------------
import { SAVE_COMMENT } from "actions/types";

export function saveComment(comment) {
  return {
    type: SAVE_COMMENT,
    payload: comment,
  };
}


//reducer ------------------
import { SAVE_COMMENT } from "actions/types";

export default function (state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SAVE_COMMENT:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

//component ------------------
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { saveComment } from "actions/index";

class CommentBox extends Component {
  state = {
    comment: "",
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ comment: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //call an action creator and save the comment
    this.props.saveComment(this.state.comment);

    this.setState({ comment: "" }); //to empty-out the textarea
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <h4>Add a Comment</h4>
        <textarea value={this.state.comment} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <div>
          <button>Submit Comment</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    saveComment: () => dispatch(saveComment()),
  };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CommentBox);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    saveComment: () => dispatch(saveComment()),
  };
};
```

to

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    saveComment: (comment) => dispatch(saveComment(comment)),
  };
};
```

Comment: Great, it worked. Thanks, can you please elaborate on the ans a bit more. I really want to ans

Comment: I'm not sure what to elaborate on - you're passing in `props.saveComment` to the component, but what you were passing in didn't do anything with the comment you wanted to store in your state.  This makes it so it does

Comment: great help Dave ✌✌